# Prove E is an equivalence relation over $ℝ^2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, alternative-proof, equivalence-relations, solution-verification

Consider the relation E over $ℝ^2$ defined as follows:

$(x_1, y_1) \space E \space (x_2,y_2)$ if $ \exists k \in ℝ (k \neq 0 \land (kx_1, ky_1) = (x_2, y_2)$

I was wondering if anyone has a better method of proving this and also if you can critique my writing to see where i need more work.

My working:

$\\$

Lemma 1: The binary relation $(kx_1, ky_1) E (x_2, y_2)$ is reflexive.

Proof:

Consider an arbitrary $x_2, y_2 \in ℝ^2$. We will prove that $(kx_1, ky_1) = (x_2, y_2)$ is reflexive, where $k$ \in ℝ.

Lets assume $x_1 = x_2, y_1 = y_2$ and $k_1=1$. Notice that with these values $(kx_1, ky_1) = (x_2, y_2)$. Therefore $(kx_1, ky_1) E (x_2, y_2)$ is reflexive.

$\\$
$\\$

Lemma 2: The binary relation $(kx_1, ky_1) E (x_2, y_2)$ is symmetric.

Proof: Consider an arbitrary $x_2, y_2 \in ℝ^2$. We will prove that, $(kx_1, ky_1) E (x_2, y_2)$ is symmetric. Lets assume $(kx_1, ky_1) = (x_2, y_2)$ where $k$ is an integer. We will now prove $(ax_2, ay_2) E (x_2, y_2)$, where a is a real number.

Lets assume the real number, $a=1/k$. We can see that $(ax_2, ay_2) = (x_1, y_1)$. Therefore, we can conclude that $(x_1, y_1) \space E \space (x_2, y_2)$ is symmetric.

$\\$
$\\$

Lemma 3: The binary relation $(x_1, y_1) \space E \space (x_2, y_2)$ is transitive.

Proof: Consider $x_2, y_2$ to be arbitrary integers, such that $x_2 \in ℝ^2 \cap y_2 \in ℝ^2 $. Lets assume there exists an integer, $k$ where $k \neq 0$ and $(kx_1, ky_1) = (x_2, y_2)$. We will prove that $(x_1, y_1) \space E \space (x_2, y_2)$ is transitive.

Lets assume $x_3, y_3$ are arbitary integers where $x_3 \in ℝ^2 \cap y_3 \in ℝ^2$. To prove that $(x_1, y_1) \space E \space (x_2, y_2)$ is transitive, consider $a$ to be an integer where $(ax_2, ay_2) = (x_3, y_3)$.

Notice that $(x_1, y_1) E (x_2, y_2) \cap (x_2, y_2) E (x_3, y_3)$. By multiplying $x$, and $y$, by the integers a and k we can see that $(x_1, y_1) E (x_3, y_3)$.

Therefore we can conclude that $(x_1, y_1) E (x_2, y_2)$ is transitive.

Comment: It is not clear to me how you define your equivalence relation. Where does $k$ come from? In your proof you say $k$ is an integer (i.e. comes from $\mathbb Z$) and in lemma 2 you say $a$ is an integer and set $a = \frac{1}{2}$, which is a noninteger rational number, i.e. in $\mathbb Q \setminus \mathbb Z$

Comment: Regarding your question: At some point you have to get your hands dirty and I feel like this is one of the instances where it is by far the easiest to quickly check the axioms of an equivalence relation per hand. You may try to proof a more general statement though, like: given a vector space $V$ over some field $K$ show that $v_1 \sim v_2 :\Leftrightarrow \exists k \in K \setminus \{0\}: v_1 = kv_2$ defines an equivalence relation on $V$...

Comment: I am wondering if you defined your relation as you should have. Where is y1 in your definition of relation E?

Comment: @PrudiiArca I've just edited the equivalence relation, it should show where $k$ comes from.

Comment: @Edcookie274 I've just edited the some parts of the equivalence relation and the proof. Realised there was a typo.

Comment: Ok, now finish the problem by describing the equivalence classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just $1$ comment:

> Lemma 1: The binary relation $(kx_1, ky_1) E (x_2, y_2)$ is reflexive.

You may want to write $E$ instead of the whole $(kx_1, ky_1) E (x_2, y_2)$ (in several other places as well).

The rest of your work seems legitimate to me.